# MvvmCross and PCL Service Layer - how to use OS specific functions

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

Been googling it for a while, but found nothing really good.

So, the thing is, in `MVVM Cross` guides our solution (for mobile platforms) is separated on, as example, `HelloWorld.Core` project and few platform specific projects, as example `HelloWorld.Android.UI`.

You can see full tutorial here https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/tipcalc-tutorial/the-tip-calc-tutorial

And, the thing is, in our `.Core` project we creating Services, ViewModels and we registering it in MVVM Cross provided IoC-container.

In example which provided by the MvvmCross documentation `Service` implementation is really simple, just one function like that

```
    public class CalculationService: ICalculationService
    {
        public double TipAmount(double subTotal, int generosity)
        {
            return subTotal * ((double)generosity)/100.0;
        }
    }
```

so we just go ahead, registering it in our `App.cs` and then its fine to use in binded `ViewModel`

```
public class App: MvxApplication
    {
        public App()
        {
            Mvx.RegisterType<ICalculationService, CalculationService>();
            Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAppStart>(new MvxAppStart<HomeViewModel>());
        }
    }
```

View model code :

```
public class TipViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        readonly ICalculation _calculation;

        public TipViewModel(ICalculation calculation)
        {
            _calculation = calculation;
        }

    // ...

        double _tip;

        public double Tip
        {
            get {
                return _tip;
            }
            set
            {
                _tip = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Tip);
            }
        }

        void Recalculate()
        {
            Tip = _calculation.TipAmount(SubTotal, Generosity);
        }
    }
```

But the thing is, when I started playing around with that, I decided, to, let say, code some simple local storage data scanner to find some specific files.

Simple code example:

```
 public class SimpleDataScanner : IBaseDataScanner
    {
        private string _basePath { get; set; }

        private List<string> _scanResult { get; set; }

        public SimpleDataScanner()
        {
            _basePath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            _scanResult = new List<string>();
        }

        public List<string> BasicDataScan(string startPath = null)
        {
            string startFolder = _basePath;

            if (startPath.Length > 0 && startPath.Length != null)
            {
                startFolder = Path.Combine(_basePath, startPath);
            }

            try
            {
                TreeScan(startFolder);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            return _scanResult;

        }

        private void TreeScan(string path)
        {
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                if (Path.HasExtension("pdf"))
                {
                    _scanResult.Add(file);
                }
            }
            foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                TreeScan(dir);
            }
        }
    }
```

And, as I found out, the problems are:

1) I can't use Android specific functions and properties in PCL

2) I can't use reference in my PCL `Core` project to, lets say, some other `Android` class lib project

So, I can't create working Service which means I can't register it in IoC-container and pass to ViewModel.

Whats the way of doing such things?
Any tutorials? Or I getting whole idea wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the interface in your platform code, and register the concrete implementation against the interface in `Setup.cs` inside your platform project. So in your case, `IDataScanner` would exist inside your `Core` project, while `SimpleDataScanner` would live in the Android project.

Inside `Setup.cs`, you'd register the concrete implementation like this:

```
protected override void InitializeFirstChance()
{
    base.InitializeFirstChance();

    Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IDataScanner>(() => new SimpleDataScanner());
}
```

Essentially, if the interface requires platform-specific or full .NET framework code to implement, those per-platform implementations live in the platforms and are registered in the platform setup. If both the interface and the implementation are shared within the `Core` project, the dependency can be registered in `App.cs`.